# Jumping from one rail to an other rail

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have following observable:

```
  let oSelectOb = oSelect
    .map(function (oEvent) {
      return oEvent.getSource();
    })
    .map(function (oControl) {
      let oItem = oControl.getSelectedItem();
      let aKeys = oItem.getKey().split("/");
      return {plant: aKeys[0], wc: aKeys[1]};
    })
    .flatMap(function (oSelectedItem) {

      let oModel = self.getModel("weightProtocolService");
      let oPlantFilter = new Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.plant);
      let oWcFilter = new Filter("WorkCenter", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.wc);

      return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        oModel.read("/CostCenterCalendarSet", {
          success: function (oData, oResponse) {
            observer.next(oResponse);
          },
          error: function (oError) {
            observer.error(oError);
          },
          filters: [oPlantFilter, oWcFilter]
        });
      });
    })
    .map(function (oData) {
      return oData.data.results;
    });
```

As the next step, I want to validate if the `oData.data.results` array is greater then 0, if yes, then it should continue passing the array.
If the array is equal zero, then it should take an other observable.

Like jumping from one rail to an other rail, when something goes wrong(if/else scenario).

**Update**

```
oSelect
   .map(function (oEvent) {
    // Clean up dates
    let oModel = self.getModel("vmCalSpecialDates");
    oModel.setProperty("/specialDates", []);

    return oEvent.getSource();
  })
  .map(function (oControl) {
    let oItem = oControl.getSelectedItem();
    let aKeys = oItem.getKey().split("/");
    return {plant: aKeys[0], wc: aKeys[1]};
  })
  .flatMap(function (oSelectedItem) {

    let oModel = self.getModel("weightProtocolService");
    let oPlantFilter = new Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.plant);
    let oWcFilter = new Filter("WorkCenter", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.wc);

    return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
      oModel.read("/CostCenterCalendarSet", {
        success: function (oData, oResponse) {
          observer.next(oResponse);
        },
        error: function (oError) {
          observer.error(oError);
        },
        filters: [oPlantFilter, oWcFilter]
      });
    });
  })
  .map(function (oData) {
    return oData.data.results;
  })
  .filter(function (aData) {
    return aData.length > 0;
  })
  .flatMap(function (aData) {
    return Rx.Observable.from(aData)
  })
  .filter(function (oData) {
    let oToday = new Date();
    return oData.InspectionDate.getTime() > oToday.getTime();
  });
```

as you can see on the first map function, I could cleanup there:

```
// Clean up dates
let oModel = self.getModel("vmCalSpecialDates");
oModel.setProperty("/specialDates", []);
```

But I think, this is not a clean way to solve the problem. It breaks the functional programming ideology.

**Update 2**
I tried as follow:

```
  return oSelect
    .map(function (oEvent) {
      // Clean up dates
      /*let oModel = self.getModel("vmCalSpecialDates");
      oModel.setProperty("/specialDates", []);*/

      return oEvent.getSource();
    })
    .map(function (oControl) {
      let oItem = oControl.getSelectedItem();
      let aKeys = oItem.getKey().split("/");
      return {plant: aKeys[0], wc: aKeys[1]};
    })
    .flatMap(function (oSelectedItem) {

      let oModel = self.getModel("weightProtocolService");
      let oPlantFilter = new Filter("Plant", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.plant);
      let oWcFilter = new Filter("WorkCenter", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, oSelectedItem.wc);

      return Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        oModel.read("/CostCenterCalendarSet", {
          success: function (oData, oResponse) {
            observer.next(oResponse);
          },
          error: function (oError) {
            observer.error(oError);
          },
          filters: [oPlantFilter, oWcFilter]
        });
      });
    })
    .map(function (oData) {
      return oData.data.results;
    })
    .flatMap(function (aData) {
      if (aData.length === 0) {
        return Rx.Observable.empty();
      }
      return Rx.Observable.from(aData)
    })
    .filter(function (oData) {
      let oToday = new Date();
      return oData.InspectionDate.getTime() > oToday.getTime();
    });
```

and the subscribe method does not get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe looks like a typical `mergeMap()`:

```
.mergeMap(function(oData) {
    return oData.data.results.length > 0
       ? Observable.of(oData.data.results)
       : Observable.empty();
});
```

Comment: No, may be I do not describe clearly, what I mean. If the array is equal zero , then it should interrupt the the method chaining and go an other way. As describe here http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/.

Comment: So by "go other way" you mean end the Observable chain? You cam use `Observable.empty()` for this.

Comment: If the array is empty, then I want to do some cleanup on other variable for example.